# Python - blit with subplots only plotting last subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, blit

I am trying to plot multiple subplots in real-time in my python application. Ideally, I should also be able to plot multiple lines in each subplot, but for simplicity here I assume one line per subplot.
In order to do so efficiently (I am looking for fast plots), I am trying to extend one example I found online (https://taher-zadeh.com/speeding-matplotlib-plotting-times-real-time-monitoring-purposes/) to my case. My code is:

```
import time    
# for Mac OSX
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')   
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import random

def test_fps(use_blit=True):

    ax1.cla()
    ax1.set_title('Sensor Input vs. Time -')
    ax1.set_xlabel('Time (s)')
    ax1.set_ylabel('Sensor Input (mV)')
    ax2.cla()
    ax2.set_title('Sensor Input vs. Time -' )
    ax2.set_xlabel('Time (s)')
    ax2.set_ylabel('Sensor Input (mV)')
    ax3.cla()
    ax3.set_title('Sensor Input vs. Time -')
    ax3.set_xlabel('Time (s)')
    ax3.set_ylabel('Sensor Input (mV)')
    ax4.cla()
    ax4.set_title('Sensor Input vs. Time -')
    ax4.set_xlabel('Time (s)')
    ax4.set_ylabel('Sensor Input (mV)')

    plt.ion()  # Set interactive mode ON, so matplotlib will not be blocking the window
    plt.show(False)  # Set to false so that the code doesn't stop here

    cur_time = time.time()
    ax1.hold(True)
    ax2.hold(True)
    ax3.hold(True)
    ax4.hold(True)

    x, y = [], []
    times = [time.time() - cur_time]  # Create blank array to hold time values
    y.append(0)

    line1, = ax1.plot(times, y, '.-', alpha=0.8, color="gray", markerfacecolor="red")
    line2, = ax2.plot(times, y, '.-', alpha=0.8, color="gray", markerfacecolor="red")
    line3, = ax3.plot(times, y, '.-', alpha=0.8, color="gray", markerfacecolor="red")
    line4, = ax4.plot(times, y, '.-', alpha=0.8, color="gray", markerfacecolor="red")


    fig.show()
    fig.canvas.draw()

    if use_blit:
        background1 = fig.canvas.copy_from_bbox(ax1.bbox) # cache the background
        background2 = fig.canvas.copy_from_bbox(ax2.bbox) # cache the background
        background3 = fig.canvas.copy_from_bbox(ax3.bbox) # cache the background
        background4 = fig.canvas.copy_from_bbox(ax4.bbox) # cache the background

    tic = time.time()

    niter = 200
    i = 0
    while i < niter:

        fields = random.random() * 100

        times.append(time.time() - cur_time)
        y.append(fields)

        # this removes the tail of the data so you can run for long hours. You can cache this
        # and store it in a pickle variable in parallel.

        if len(times) > 50:
           del y[0]
           del times[0]

        xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = [min(times) / 1.05, max(times) * 1.1, -5,110]

        # feed the new data to the plot and set the axis limits again
        plt.axis([xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])

        if use_blit:
            fig.canvas.restore_region(background1)    # restore background
            line1.set_xdata(times)
            line1.set_ydata(y)
            ax1.draw_artist(line1)                   # redraw just the points
            fig.canvas.blit(ax1.bbox)                # fill in the axes rectangle


            fig.canvas.restore_region(background2)    # restore background
            line2.set_xdata(times)
            line2.set_ydata(y)
            ax2.draw_artist(line2)                   # redraw just the points
            fig.canvas.blit(ax2.bbox)

            fig.canvas.restore_region(background3)    # restore background
            line3.set_xdata(times)
            line3.set_ydata(y)
            ax3.draw_artist(line3)                   # redraw just the points
            fig.canvas.blit(ax3.bbox)         

            fig.canvas.restore_region(background4)    # restore background
            line4.set_xdata(times)
            line4.set_ydata(y)
            ax4.draw_artist(line4)                   # redraw just the points
            fig.canvas.blit(ax4.bbox) 

        else:
            fig.canvas.draw()

        fig.canvas.flush_events()

        i += 1

    fps = niter / (time.time() - tic)
    return fps
```

and

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(4, 1, 1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(4, 1, 2)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(4, 1, 3)
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(4, 1, 4)
fps1 = test_fps(use_blit=True)
```

The problem with this code is that is only plotting onto the last subplots and Leaves the Others blank.

[image]

I am new to python and I guess this is a very silly question but I have not managed to figure it out yet so every hint would be very helpful to me.
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the current implementation you set the axis limits only for the last plot, i.e. `plt.axis([xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])` works on the last active subplot.

Instead you would need to update all of the axes `ax1` to `ax4`,

```
ax1.axis([xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])
ax2.axis([xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])
ax3.axis([xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])
ax4.axis([xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])
```

to let their limits follow the data.

Additionally it seems beneficial to update the data outside the blitting condition, such that one can compare blitting without blitting.

Complete code:

```
import time    
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')   
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import random

def test_fps(use_blit=True):

    ax1.cla()
    ax1.set_title('Sensor Input vs. Time -')
    ax1.set_xlabel('Time (s)')
    ax1.set_ylabel('Sensor Input (mV)')
    ax2.cla()
    ax2.set_title('Sensor Input vs. Time -' )
    ax2.set_xlabel('Time (s)')
    ax2.set_ylabel('Sensor Input (mV)')
    ax3.cla()
    ax3.set_title('Sensor Input vs. Time -')
    ax3.set_xlabel('Time (s)')
    ax3.set_ylabel('Sensor Input (mV)')
    ax4.cla()
    ax4.set_title('Sensor Input vs. Time -')
    ax4.set_xlabel('Time (s)')
    ax4.set_ylabel('Sensor Input (mV)')

    plt.ion()  # Set interactive mode ON, so matplotlib will not be blocking the window
    plt.show(False)  # Set to false so that the code doesn't stop here

    cur_time = time.time()
    #    ax1.hold(True)
    #    ax2.hold(True)
    #    ax3.hold(True)
    #    ax4.hold(True)

    x, y = [], []
    times = [time.time() - cur_time]  # Create blank array to hold time values
    y.append(0)

    line1, = ax1.plot(times, y, '.-', alpha=0.8, color="gray", markerfacecolor="red")
    line2, = ax2.plot(times, y, '.-', alpha=0.8, color="gray", markerfacecolor="red")
    line3, = ax3.plot(times, y, '.-', alpha=0.8, color="gray", markerfacecolor="red")
    line4, = ax4.plot(times, y, '.-', alpha=0.8, color="gray", markerfacecolor="red")


    fig.show()
    fig.canvas.draw()

    if use_blit:
        background1 = fig.canvas.copy_from_bbox(ax1.bbox) # cache the background
        background2 = fig.canvas.copy_from_bbox(ax2.bbox) # cache the background
        background3 = fig.canvas.copy_from_bbox(ax3.bbox) # cache the background
        background4 = fig.canvas.copy_from_bbox(ax4.bbox) # cache the background

    tic = time.time()

    niter = 200
    i = 0
    while i < niter:

        fields = random.random() * 100

        times.append(time.time() - cur_time)
        y.append(fields)

        # this removes the tail of the data so you can run for long hours. You can cache this
        # and store it in a pickle variable in parallel.

        if len(times) > 50:
           del y[0]
           del times[0]

        xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = [min(times) / 1.05, max(times) * 1.1, -5,110]

        # feed the new data to the plot and set the axis limits again
        ax1.axis([xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])
        ax2.axis([xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])
        ax3.axis([xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])
        ax4.axis([xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])

        line1.set_data(times, y)
        line2.set_data(times, y)
        line3.set_data(times, y)
        line4.set_data(times, y)

        if use_blit:
            fig.canvas.restore_region(background1)    # restore background
            ax1.draw_artist(line1)                   # redraw just the points
            fig.canvas.blit(ax1.bbox)                # fill in the axes rectangle

            fig.canvas.restore_region(background2)    # restore background
            ax2.draw_artist(line2)                   # redraw just the points
            fig.canvas.blit(ax2.bbox)

            fig.canvas.restore_region(background3)    # restore background
            ax3.draw_artist(line3)                   # redraw just the points
            fig.canvas.blit(ax3.bbox)         

            fig.canvas.restore_region(background4)    # restore background
            ax4.draw_artist(line4)                   # redraw just the points
            fig.canvas.blit(ax4.bbox) 

        else:
            fig.canvas.draw()

        fig.canvas.flush_events()

        i += 1

    fps = niter / (time.time() - tic)
    return fps

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(4, 1, 1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(4, 1, 2)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(4, 1, 3)
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(4, 1, 4)
fps1 = test_fps(use_blit=True)
print fps1
```

Just to note this runs without blitting at 10fps and with blitting at 16 fps on my computer.

Comment: This solution works for me, thank you very much. Anyway, on my PC I got 20 fps without blit and 96 fps with blit, I would say a good improvement.

Comment: Oh, that's indeed great. If you have time, I would be interested to know the framerates you get for the matplotlib part of [this answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40139416/4124317) to compare it to the 18 and 28 fps I got there.

Comment: Well I do not have enough reputation to add a comment under your question. Anyway, I got approx. 13 fps without blit and 16 fps with blit by running the copy-pasted code of the matplotlib version.

Comment: That seems reasonable, but opens the question why you got a so much higher framerate in this exmple of yours. Anyways thanks for sharing this.