# Only last subplot shows (others are blank) and it is the wrong plot

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, subplot

I'm having trouble setting up subplots in matplotlib. Below is a screenshot of the layout I am trying to achieve. I've only gone up through ax4, as I have encountered two issues. Code is also below. (Note that on their own, the functions plot as expected.) I want to continue using "subplot2grid" instead of the other options, and I'm using Python 2.7

**Expected behavior:**
Plots ax1, ax2, and ax3 should be a World Shade Relief Map, with position as shown in desired layout below.
Plot ax4 should be a scatter plot, with position as shown in desired layout below.

**Actual behavior:**
Plots ax1, ax2, and ax3 are all blank
Plot ax4 is not a scatter, but it's actually the map; layout is also wrong.

I thought I was missing a "hold on" type feature, but it looks like [that's not how matplotlib works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21465988/python-equivalent-to-hold-on-in-matlab).
I also made sure I [defined the plot limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44107777/python-blit-with-subplots-only-plotting-last-subplots) in myplotA function.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from random import randint

def myplotA(plotnum, title):
    south = 34.0129656032
    north = 34.721878622
    west = -116.7615176
    east = -116.336918412
    center = [(east + west) / 2, (north + south) / 2]
    m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=west, llcrnrlat=south, urcrnrlon=east, urcrnrlat=north, resolution='c', epsg=4326, lon_0=center[0], lat_0=center[1], suppress_ticks=False)
    img = m.arcgisimage(service="World_Shaded_Relief", xpixels=2000)
    img.set_alpha(0.5)
    plt.xticks(rotation='horizontal')
    plotnum.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter(useOffset=False))
    plotnum.axis([west, east, south, north])
    for label in (plotnum.get_xticklabels() + plotnum.get_yticklabels()):label.set_fontsize(9)
    plt.gca().set_title(title, fontsize=12)

def myplotB(plotnum, title):
    x = [randint(0, 10) for i in range(0, 6)]
    y = [randint(0, 10) for i in range(0, 6)]
    plotnum.scatter(x, y, s=4)
    plotnum.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter(useOffset=False))
    plt.xlabel('xlabel', fontsize=8)
    plt.ylabel('ylabel', fontsize=8)
    plt.gca().set_title(title, fontsize=12)



fig = plt.figure(figsize=(11, 17))
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((8, 3), (0, 0), rowspan=4, colspan=1)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((8, 3), (0, 1), rowspan=4, colspan=1)
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((8, 3), (0, 2), rowspan=4, colspan=1)
ax4 = plt.subplot2grid((8, 3), (5, 0), rowspan=1, colspan=2)
myplotA(ax1, 'ax1')
myplotA(ax2, 'ax2')
myplotA(ax3, 'ax3')
myplotB(ax4, 'ax4')
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.1, bottom=0.1, right=0.9, top=0.9, wspace=.1, hspace=.1)
fig.savefig(outpath + '\\' + 'mytest.pdf')
```

**Desired Layout**
[Desired Layout Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LggvI.jpg)

**Actual Result**
[Actual Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9TB3.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You pass the axes to the plotting functions, but inside of those you need to actually ***use*** those passed axes. Else all the `plt` commands will apply to the currently active axes, which is the last one you create.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from random import randint

def myplotA(ax, title):
    south = 34.0129656032
    north = 34.721878622
    west = -116.7615176
    east = -116.336918412
    center = [(east + west) / 2, (north + south) / 2]
    m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=west, llcrnrlat=south, urcrnrlon=east, urcrnrlat=north, 
                resolution='c', epsg=4326, lon_0=center[0], lat_0=center[1], 
                suppress_ticks=False, ax=ax)
    img = m.arcgisimage(service="World_Shaded_Relief", xpixels=2000)
    img.set_alpha(0.5)
    plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation='horizontal')
    plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels() + ax.get_yticklabels(), fontsize=9)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter(useOffset=False))
    ax.axis([west, east, south, north])
    ax.set_title(title, fontsize=12)

def myplotB(ax, title):
    x = [randint(0, 10) for i in range(0, 6)]
    y = [randint(0, 10) for i in range(0, 6)]
    ax.scatter(x, y, s=4)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter(useOffset=False))
    ax.set_xlabel('xlabel', fontsize=8)
    ax.set_ylabel('ylabel', fontsize=8)
    ax.set_title(title, fontsize=12)



fig = plt.figure(figsize=(11, 8))
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((8, 3), (0, 0), rowspan=4, colspan=1)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((8, 3), (0, 1), rowspan=4, colspan=1)
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((8, 3), (0, 2), rowspan=4, colspan=1)
ax4 = plt.subplot2grid((8, 3), (5, 0), rowspan=1, colspan=2)
myplotA(ax1, 'ax1')
myplotA(ax2, 'ax2')
myplotA(ax3, 'ax3')
myplotB(ax4, 'ax4')
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.1, bottom=0.1, right=0.9, top=0.9, wspace=.1, hspace=.1)
fig.savefig('mytest.pdf')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest -- I wasn't able to get it to work with your code, but your description of the problem led me to a solution (posted as answer)

Comment: You mean if you copy and paste the code from this answer you get a different result than shown in the image?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

I tried your code above, but still same plot as shown in the "actual results" part of the OP. However, your words describe the problem: I'm activating the axis, and then activating the next one before plotting. Below does the trick--perhaps this is what you had anyhow and just mistakenly copy/pasted the original code. Thanks for point me in the right direction.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(11, 17))
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((8, 3), (0, 0), rowspan=4, colspan=1)
myplotA(ax1, 'ax1')
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((8, 3), (0, 1), rowspan=4, colspan=1)
myplotA(ax2, 'ax2')
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((8, 3), (0, 2), rowspan=4, colspan=1)
myplotA(ax3, 'ax3')
ax4 = plt.subplot2grid((8, 3), (4, 0), rowspan=1, colspan=2)
myplotB(ax4, 'ax4')
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.1, bottom=0.1, right=0.9, top=0.9, wspace=.1, hspace=.1)
fig.savefig(outpath + '\\' + 'mytest.pdf')
```

[Link to image of output plot; looks as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2E6q.jpg)