# How to create a real time graph without using the Matplotlib FuncAnimation

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have been trying to figure out how to make a real time updating graph using Matplotlib, without using `FuncAnimation()` because it was too slow for my final purpose. I read through [This Article](https://bastibe.de/2013-05-30-speeding-up-matplotlib.html), which explains how to speed up the plotting in Matplotlib. I then tried to implement his method with [a real time graph](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/graph-sensor-data-with-python-and-matplotlib/speeding-up-the-plot-animation) method, but unfortuanately I still have only basic Python/Matplotlib skills to do such a thing.

I was able to get as far as creating an x and y limit and creating a blank line which I would like to update in a while loop with random numbers for now. 
I am able to create random numbers every loop but I am unable to update the numbers to the graph. I do not want the x values to change but rather the y values to change while being updated. Something that looks like a heart monitor would for example. Here is my following code up to where I am stuck:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

x_len = 100
y_range = [-1,10]
xs = list(range(0,100))
ys = [0] * x_len

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot(xs,ys)
ax.set_ylim(y_range)
plt.show(block=False)
fig.canvas.draw()


while True:
    y = random.randint(-10,10)
    line.set_ydata(ys)
    ax.draw_artist(ax.patch)
    ax.draw_artist(line)
    fig.canvas.flush_events()

    print("one loop")
    print(y)
```

Comment: FuncAnimation is not slower than any other method you can use. It could be that matplotlib itself is too slow for your purpose though.

Comment: Possibly, but everyone keeps directing me to to the first article in my main post. Might as well give it a try before I move on.

Comment: Let me direct you to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50390093/4124317) which shows how to use FuncAnimation and get a framerate above 80 for an image. Now a single line is of course a lot less data to update. So I changed that example to your case of a line with 100 points and it runs with 250 fps. That is 10 times faster than the human brain can resolve, hence it should be sufficient.

Comment: Thank you, I will attempt to use FuncAnimation again and apply this to my work.

Comment: The `blit=True` is kind of the trick here if the axes don't change. axes creation is kind of slow.