# How can I autoscale an animated plot with pyplot?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I have the following code that generates an animated plot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

x = []
y = []
t = 0

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot([0,0])

ax.set_ylim((-2,2))
ax.set_xlim((0,10))

def animate(i):
    global x,y,t
    line.set_ydata(y)
    line.set_xdata(x)
    x.append(t)
    y.append(np.sin(t))
    t += 0.05
    return line,


def init():
    line.set_ydata(np.ma.array(x, mask=True))
    return line,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, np.arange(1, 200), init_func=init, interval=25, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

How can I make it so that the plot is scaled to fit the data? I would like the axes and scale to automatically adjust.

Comment: I have figured out how to scale the data with `ax.relim()` and `ax.autoscale_view()`, but the ticks do not change.

Comment: If you want to change the plot limits (e.g. via `ax.relim()` and `ax.autoscale_view()`)  you need to redraw the axes. This is prevented by `blit=True`. Blitting only makes sense if you want to redraw a limited portion of your figure. Set `blit=False` to update the complete canvas and with it the axes scales.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks, but turning off blitting hurts performance so much my fan kicks on. Is there a way to update the ticks without causing such a large drop in performance?

Comment: Do you not observe an equally large drop in performance already when using `ax.relim() and ax.autoscale_view()`? I guess you can write a custom function to blit the axes as well, but of course the larger the area to blit the closer it gets to redrawing everything.

Comment: My CPU usage stays at around 15% when using blitting, and jumps up to around 40% with blitting turned off. Where can I figure out how to scale the axes while keeping my laptop cool?

Comment: Let me put it like this: Matplotlib does not provide any means to blit the axes. But you may write a custom function that does. You would start by understanding the blitting mechanism and looking around for examples that use manual blitting (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40126176/fast-live-plotting-in-matplotlib-pyplot)). You may then extend this to use a larger bounding box. However I still have the feeling that once you blit the axes performance would equally drop. One would need to do it in order to find out.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the help! I don't think I'm skilled enough to do that, so I'll look for a different library for liveplotting.

Answer (score 0):

You can add following line

```
ax.set_ylim(y.min(), y.max())
```

in your **animation** function. Then the similar code can be written as

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
y = np.cos(x)
t = 0

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot(x, y)


def animate(i):
    y = i*np.sin(i*x)
    line.set_ydata(y)
    
    ax.set_ylim(y.min()*1.1, y.max()*1.1)
    
    return line,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig=fig, func=animate, frames=range(20), interval=250)
plt.close()
ani
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).