# How to plot live data using python?

Tags: python

I have a bunch of coupled differential equations and I want to see what the curves of the output after differentiating look like but in real time ie. While it's differentiating for each timestep I want to look at how they behave in a live graph. I want to slowly see how the curves are formed.

I have checked online for live graph ideas but most of them save the data somewhere and plot when data in updated. In my case the differentiation is extremely fast so I would also need a delay function which will slowly plot each timestep data on the graph (Live).

Example sudo code

```
def model(timestep, inital_data):
    dxdt = x+y
    dydt = dxdt + k + c
    
    plot(dxdt, timestep)
    plot(dydt, timestep)
```

Comment: Everyone who claimed to have searched or "checked online" tend to not have checked thoroughly enough. Have you [checked answers like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50480188/)?  Also, it's "pseudo" (typically written as [pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode)), not "sudo" (which is something completely different).